# SQL Select twice from one table

Tags: mysql, sql, phpmyadmin

I'm using PHPmyAdmin to access my database and I have this table:

```
ID  NAME  SUPERVISOR  CITY SALARY      
 9  Lucy              NY   100000    
13  Max            9  TN   50000   
 5  Peter          9  TN   60000    
70  Kid            5  HI   40000
```

I need to select this:

```
NAME  SUPERVISOR
Lucy  -
Max   Lucy
Peter Lucy
Kid   Peter
```

I've tried solving it for more than half a hour, but nothing helps. It must be something really easy. Can you help?

Answer (score 2):

You can get your result with a `LEFT JOIN` on the same table:

```
Select      T1.Name, T2.Name As Supervisor
From        YourTable   T1
Left Join   YourTable   T2  On  T1.Supervisor = T2.ID
```

Answer (score 1):

You need [MYSQL Self Join](http://www.mysqltutorial.org/mysql-self-join/) feature to get result

```
SELECT e1.name, IFNULL(e2.name,'--') SUPERVISORName 
FROM   t e1 
   LEFT JOIN t e2 
   ON e1.SUPERVISOR  = e2.ID
Order by e1.SUPERVISOR 

NAME    SUPERVISORName
Lucy    --
Kid     Peter
Max     Lucy
Peter   Lucy
```

[SAMPLE SQL FIDDLE](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/a1fc6/7)

Answer (score 1):

This should do it - a self join:

```
SELECT t1.Name, t2.Name AS Supervisor
FROM myTable t1
LEFT JOIN myTable t2 ON t1.Supervisor = t2.Id
```

If you really want to show a dash, `-`, instead of `null` you can use:

```
COALESCE(t2.Name,'-') AS Supervisor
```

Answer (score 0):

You can do a join in the same table.

```
SELECT person.NAME AS NAME, sv.NAME AS SUPERVISOR FROM person LEFT JOIN person AS sv ON person.SUPERVISOR = sv.ID
```